# How To Change Title For Alert Dialog Box For Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome Extension for my first time and I am trying to use alert() to create a dialog box however when it runs I encounter a problem. The title isn't the name of the extension - instead it is the extension ID ("chrome-extension://..... says").

[image: Screenshot]

I want the title to say the name of the extension, not the ID. Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  //Extension Details
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons" : 
  {
    "16": "PI-Logo.png",
    "32": "PI-Logo.png",
    "64": "PI-Logo.png"
  },
  //Main HTML Action
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "PI-Logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  //Permissions
  "permissions":
  [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides": 
  {
    "newtab" : "newtab.html"
  },
  //Scripts
  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["myScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background":
  {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**myScript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Hello World!");
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert(response);
});
```

I don't know that much about javascript or HTML - I'm an amateur at this. Any help would be appreciated as to how I could fix this. Thank you!

Comment: For the record - please don't use snippets in future unless it's a short demo code that can actually be run. Just use code blocks - indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: Oh okay sorry this is my first time posting. Thanks for the info, I will do that in the future!

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. The JavaScript alert box title can't be changed for security reason (fishing and stuff like that).

[There is plenty of library for modal pop-up](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20modal%20dialog) in JavaScript, but in your case, it can be difficult to because you have to inject it in all pages...

An other way to do almost what you want is to use the desktop notification API. It open little pop-up on the bottom right corner of the screen and you can customize the title. [More information here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications).

Comment: Is it possible to change the title to the chrome extension name? 
It was done in this tutorial - I just don't know how.
https://youtu.be/wjiku6X-hd8?t=4m3s

Comment: @PenguixDarke I don't know it's weird I have never successfuly done this.